# Fetch Two Arrays in 1 while loop (not working)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch arrays from two queries. The result only gets the first index.

```
while(($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) && ($index = mysql_fetch_array($query2)))
{
   $leaveID = $row2['leaveID'];
   $personID = $index['personID'];
   $Person_Type = $index['Person_Type'];

   if ($Person_Type == 'Regular') 
   {
      $Sick_Remaining_Days = 10 - $Sick_Total_Days;
   }else{
      $Sick_Remaining_Days = 5 - $Sick_Total_Days;
   }    

   echo "<tr>";
   echo ($leaveID == $personID) ? "<td>$Sick_Remaining_Days</td>" : "<td>--</td>";
   echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

Comment: How long are both results? This loop will finish when each reaches the end of either of them.

Comment: Maybe there's an error in your second query. Post the entire code please. Also, you should not use 'mysql' anymore because it's deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead. Safer and better is PDO because of its prepared statements.

Comment: Do both your queries has same row count?

Comment: The query1 has 2 records and the query2 should display about 60 records.

Comment: instead store them as arrays and then go with your functions!

Comment: then your loop ends when query1 reaches the end of it,

Comment: @VijayaSankarN I'll try doing the arrays. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both queries are OK I offer two ways to loop through them depending on your needs. Hopefully one of them will help.

```
<?php
$arrayRowA = array();
$arrayRowB = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){$arrayRowA[] = $row;}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){$arrayRowB[] = $row;}


// Loop through two arrays in a square way (every combination of both arrays)
foreach($arrayRowA as $keyA => $objectA){
    foreach($arrayRowB as $keyB => $objectB){
        $leaveID        = $objectA['leaveID'];
        $personID       = $objectB['personID'];
        $Person_Type    = $objectB['Person_Type'];

        if($Person_Type == 'Regular') 
        {
            $Sick_Remaining_Days = 10 - $Sick_Total_Days;
        }else{
            $Sick_Remaining_Days = 5 - $Sick_Total_Days;
        }    

        echo "<tr>";
        echo ($leaveID == $personID) ? "<td>$Sick_Remaining_Days</td>" : "<td>--</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }
}


// Loop through two arrays in a linear way (one to one)
foreach($arrayRowA as $keyA => $objectA){
    if(isset($arrayRowB[$keyA])){
        $objectB        = $arrayRowB[$keyA];
        $leaveID        = $objectA['leaveID'];
        $personID       = $objectB['personID'];
        $Person_Type    = $objectB['Person_Type'];

        if($Person_Type == 'Regular') 
        {
            $Sick_Remaining_Days = 10 - $Sick_Total_Days;
        }else{
            $Sick_Remaining_Days = 5 - $Sick_Total_Days;
        }    

        echo "<tr>";
        echo ($leaveID == $personID) ? "<td>$Sick_Remaining_Days</td>" : "<td>--</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I did the square way but the records repeated itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("select p*, l* from person as p left join leave as l on p.personID = l.leaveID");
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)))
{
   $Person_Type = $row['Person_Type'];
   if ($Person_Type == 'Regular') 
   {
      $Sick_Remaining_Days = 10 - $Sick_Total_Days;
   }else{
      $Sick_Remaining_Days = 5 - $Sick_Total_Days;
   }    

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>$Sick_Remaining_Days</td>";
   echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

Comment: I cannot do joins since I am selecting different # of tables

Answer (score 0):

You should get array before while:

```
array f,s

while(first)
{
    f = ...;
}

while(second)
{
    s = ...;
}
```

And now use both array.

Or try use new http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php. Probably you losing connection to first query after use second query.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
       echo $row['id'];
       echo $row2['id'];

/* your code  */
}    `
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your post and explain your code and in how far it solves the issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more guidance.

Answer (score -1):

Use this... It is what do you search !

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
 $index = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
   echo $row['id'];
   echo $index['id'];

/* add code  */
}
```

Comment: Use mysqli_fetch_array